# Ajax посредством jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Всем привет! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает отправка данных в тег `<p id="p1"></p>.`

Вот код:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(
        { 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {                   
                var temp = data.key;
                $("#p1").text(temp);
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>    
</head>    
<body>
    <p>Входные значения:</p>
    <form id="myForm" action="ajax2.php" method="post"> 
        <p><input type="text" id="inp0" name="key"> <input type="submit" value="Отправить запрос" id="btn0"></p>
    </form>
    <p>Результаты обработки запроса:</p>
    <p id="p1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Вот обработчик ajax2.php:**

```
<?  
$key = $_POST["key"];    
echo json_encode($key);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $('#btn0').on('click', fu
        { 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {                   
                var temp = data.key;
                $("#p1").text(temp);
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Для проверки того, что приходит от сервера выведите посредством:

```
success: function(data)
                {                   
                    alert(data)
                }
```

или в консоле

```
success: function(data)
                {                   
                    console.log(data)
                }
```

Для проверки в консоле, откройте панель разработчиков (ctrl+shift+c) вкладка console и смотрите что приходит от сервера.

Мой выбор:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     var data = $('#inp0').text();
        $('#btn0').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url:url,
            type:POST,
            data:data,
            error: function(){//обработчик},
            success: function(data)
            {                   
                var temp = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#p1").html(temp);
            }) 
       });
});
```

php

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
   if (!empty($_POST)){
       print(json_encode($_POST['key']),  JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP-обработчик должен выглядеть так:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Comment: Не работает так(

Comment: В браузере установлены расширения для просмотра ajax-запросов (например, Firebug) ? Запросы успешно проходят и ответы корректные?

Comment: Я был не прав, по ошибке отключил первый подключаемый jquery.min.js .
Вот что пишет в консоли
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
На 18 строке jquery.min.js, а именно обращение к `send(c.hasContent&&c.data||null)`